# Access Configuration or Reports message

Tags: 7, users

I am not sure which change has make this error appear. I have updated from Drupal 7.2 to 7.56. Due to this I had to:

- Modify the htaccess with the [proposed code](https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2013-11-20/sa-core-2013-003-drupal-core).
- Also fix "The following module is missing from the file system ..." [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215)

What **I am trying to do is access Configuration or Reports**. When I click on them the following message appears.

> You have chosen to open:
>
> Reports
>
> that is: application/x-httpd-php(389KB)
>
> from: http://ww.mydomain.org
>
> What should Firefox do?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Are you familiar with what 7.32 was all about? If so could it be related to the security issue that got address in that release?

Comment: No, I am not aware.

Comment: your reported popup issue/warning definitely suggest that a change was applied either on your webserver's configuration or your site is a victim of the security issues from DrupalGeddon ([see this blog article that describes what one site experienced from being hacked as a result of that vulnerability](http://mattkorostoff.com/article/I-survived-drupalgeddon-how-hackers-took-over-my-site))

in the meantime, you may want to try accessing the reports pages directly by url:
/admin/reports/status   and    /admin/reports/dblog